# what is the difference in finding the basis of a subset and a basis of a null space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I just need some explanation to what the difference between a subspace and a null space is, I think that would help me understand. Thanks!

Comment: Also, how do you find the basis of a null space vs the basis of a subspace?

Answer (score 1):

A subspace of a $K$-vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$ is a non-empty subset $U\subseteq V$ which is closed under addition $+$ of vectors and scalar multiplication with scalars from $K$. The null space of a linear map $f ~:~ V \to W$ between $V$ and another $K$-vector space $W$ is defined as
$$\{v\in V ~|~ f(v) = 0\}.$$
This is a subspace, which is easily checked, but it is special in a certain sense, as it is constructed using the linear map $f$.
However, when you learn about quotient spaces, you will learn that any subspace arises as the null space of a linear map.

If you let $V=K^n$, this can also be formulated in terms f matrices. Let $A\in K^{m\times n}$. Then the null space of $A$ is
$$\{v\in V ~|~ Av=0\}.$$

Comment: Thanks! how would I find the basis of a null space? I know how to find the basis of a column space but not, null space.

Comment: If you are given a matrix $A$, this is easy. Just solve the system of linear equations $Ax=0$, i.e. make the matrix $A$ into an extended matrix $(A|0)$ and apply the Gauss algorithm in order to find the set of solutions, which is precisely the null space.